# How to illustrate the offset of the means of two datasets with large difference in count statistics in a histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to illustrate data from two different datasets in (a) histogram(s) where the count statistics differ largely. The main purpose of the plot is to highlight the offset of the means of these two datasets on the x-scale while also showing the count statistics (histogram).

Here is the dummy data:

```
library(truncnorm)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1)
a <- data.frame(x = rtruncnorm(230, a = -0.9, b = -0.7, mean = -0.8)  ) %>% mutate(group = "a")
bcd <- data.frame(x = rtruncnorm(32, a = -2.7, b = -1.6, mean = -2.1) ) %>% mutate(group = ifelse(x > -1.8, 'b',
                                                                         ifelse(x <= -1.9 & x <= -2.5, 'c', 'd' ) ) )
df <- rbind(a,bcd)
df <- df %>% mutate(dataset = ifelse(group == "a", "large", "small"))
```

My first approach is to plot both datasets in one histogram. 
The problem here is that the dataset with low count statistics (b1-b3) is not resolved well. I'm not sure if I could solve this with a dual y-scale histogram as the main goal is to get an idea on the offset of the databases and just roughly on the counts.

```
# First approach (in one plot)
p1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, fill = subgroup)) + 
  geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.4, binwidth = 0.1) +
  geom_vline(data=subset(df,dataset == "large"), aes(xintercept = mean(x)), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(data=subset(df,dataset == "small"), aes(xintercept = mean(x)), linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("segment", x=-2, xend=-1, y=100, yend=99) + 
  annotate("text", label = "Offset = mean(x2)-mean(x1)", x = -1.5, y = 96)
```

I also sketched how I plan to illustrate the offset between the means of the datasets (Something like a line between the two vertical lines showing the means).

[image: Attempt to illustrate two datasets in a histogram 1]

My second idea to illustrate this is with plotting two histograms in a grid.

```
# Second apporach (two plots in a1 grid)
ps1 <- df %>%
  filter(dataset == "large") %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.6, binwidth = 0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") + 
  # labs(x = ylabel) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank())

ps2 <- df %>% 
  filter(dataset == "small") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, fill = subgroup)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "identity",
                 alpha = 0.6, binwidth = 0.1) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")


p2 <- grid.arrange(ps2, ps1, ncol =2)
```

[image: Two datasets in histograms 2]

Here, both datasets are resolved well. However, it is not easy to show the offset of the means on the x-scales here. Moreover, the gridlines of the y-scales are not lined up.

What would be the easiest solution?

1. Can I plot the first option on a dual y-scale?
2. For the second option, couldd I plot it that the y gridlines are in line and that the x-scales are adjusted in a way that I can illustrate the offset well?

Thanks and greetings.

Comment: you need to change fill = subgroup to fill = group.  I tried to edit but the change was too small!  I would try a log y axis on one histogram. `+ scale_y_log10()`

Comment: Why do I have to change 'subgroup' to 'group'? Yeah I tried `scale_y_log10()` but that doesn't work well: 'Warning message:
Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis'

Comment: your data frame has no 'subgroup' only 'group' so it would not plot.  True the axis gives a warning - you could use `scale_y_sqrt()` for a similar effect without the warning.